# How does insteadof keyword in a Trait work

Tags: php, traits

I was just reading about traits and how multiple php traits can be used in the same php code separated by commas. I do not however understand the concept of the insteadof keyword that is used to resolve conflict in case two traits have the same function. Can anyone please explain how insteadof keyword works and how to use it to tell the engine that I am willing to use function hello() of trait A instead of that of trait B, given there are two traits A and B and a function hello() in both the traits.

Comment: Where are you reading about PHP traits? The PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.conflict) explains it very well, with examples.

Comment: From the same documentation

`<?php
trait A {
    public function smallTalk() {
        echo 'a';
    }
    public function bigTalk() {
        echo 'A';
    }
}

trait B {
    public function smallTalk() {
        echo 'b';
    }
    public function bigTalk() {
        echo 'B';
    }
}

class Talker {
    use A, B {
        B::smallTalk insteadof A;
        A::bigTalk insteadof B;
    }
}

class Aliased_Talker {
    use A, B {
        B::smallTalk insteadof A;
        A::bigTalk insteadof B;
        B::bigTalk as talk;
    }
}
?>`

Comment: Can you tell me in this code which function of which trait is being used and which is not?

Comment: I basically cannot understand this part

B::smallTalk insteadof A;

Comment: It says that when `$this->smallTalk()` is invoked, its implementation from `B` to be used (instead of the one from `A`). However, the implementation from `A` can be used by providing it an alias. The technique is shown in class `Aliased_Talker`. `Aliased_Talker::bigTalk()`  is `A::bigTalk()` and `Aliased_Talker::talk()` is `B::bigTalk()`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Explanation

According to [Traits Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php), when you have same method in multiple trait, then you can explicitly guide the program to use method of specific trait by the use of `insteadof` operator. Refer to the example below which has been borrowed from above link, Here, when `$t->smallTalk()` is invoked it calls the smallTalk method in `trait B` insteadof `trait A` which is exactly the insteadof operator has been used for here. Since Class Talker uses trait A, B and both traits have `smallTalk()` method, we explicitly tell it to use trait B's `smallTalk`.

### Example

```
<?php
trait A {
    public function smallTalk() {
        echo 'a';
    }
    public function bigTalk() {
        echo 'A';
    }
}

trait B {
    public function smallTalk() {
        echo 'b';
    }
    public function bigTalk() {
        echo 'B';
    }
}

class Talker {
    use A, B {
        B::smallTalk insteadof A;
        A::bigTalk insteadof B;
    }
}

class Aliased_Talker {
    use A, B {
        B::smallTalk insteadof A;
        A::bigTalk insteadof B;
        B::bigTalk as talk;
    }
}

$t = new Talker;
$t->smallTalk();
$t->bigTalk();
```

### Output

bA

I hope this has cleared your confusion.

Comment: Thanks Samundra the last part answers pretty much of the question. However, can you please explain the role of Aliased_Talker here, also the use of `as` keyword. Thanks

Comment: It's simple referencing so it's easier to remember. Since both traits have same method it's rather easy to alias them for further use. then you can simply replace `new Talker` with `new Aliased_Talker` and keep using the `smallTalk` and `bigTalk` method without worrying where they come from :).

Comment: @Samundra, Do you happen to understand why the syntax is `B::smallTalk insteadof A;` but not something simpler, like `smallTalk from A;`? I mean, what is the point of specifying `B::` if I can select only one trait as a source for one specific method?

Comment: @Pavel Please refer to RFC https://wiki.php.net/rfc/horizontalreuse here you'll have very detailed explanation of why traits were defined like that in PHP language itself.

Comment: If there are more than 2 traits in conflict (A, B, C) what you should use? Can you use `B::smallTalk insteadof A, C;`?

Comment: @PhoneixS Yes, we can do that. The use of alias is for the same reason ```e.g. B::bigTalk as talk``` you can similarly use ```B::smallTalk as verySmallTalk``` with alias.

Comment: But you should replace `bigTalk` with something like `scheme` or `lisp`. :P