# Is there a way to extend a trait in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, traits, php-7

I want to use functionality of an existing `trait` and create my own `trait` on top of it only to later apply it on classes.

I want to extend `Laravel SoftDeletes` trait to make `SaveWithHistory` function, so it will create a copy of a record as a deleted record. I also want to extend it with `record_made_by_user_id` field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extend Traits with Classes in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056520/extend-traits-with-classes-in-php)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37687295/470749 is a good answer.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Yes, there is. You just have to define new trait like this:

```
trait MySoftDeletes 
{
    use SoftDeletes {
        SoftDeletes::saveWithHistory as parentSaveWithHistory;
    }

    public function saveWithHistory() {
        $this->parentSaveWithHistory();

        //your implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for reference, to searchers, here is further information:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: In this context, you might find the following resource helpful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39820753/how-does-insteadof-keyword-in-a-trait-work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37687295/470749 shows another example of extending traits.

Answer (score 13):

I have different approach. `ParentSaveWithHistory` is still applicable method in this trait so at least should be defined as private.

```
trait MySoftDeletes
{
    use SoftDeletes {
        saveWithHistory as private parentSaveWithHistory; 
    }

    public function saveWithHistory()
    {
        $this->parentSaveWithHistory();
    }
}
```

Consider also 'overriding' methods in traits:

```
use SoftDeletes, MySoftDeletes {
    MySoftDeletes::saveWithHistory insteadof SoftDeletes;
}
```

This code uses method `saveWithHistory` from `MySoftDeletes`, even if it exists in `SoftDeletes`.